# package to drive a robot

Tags: ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 2 maxon motor with I have intizialed with the package epos hardware, now I have two topics, one for every motor.
My robot should be drive with a Gamepaf now i need a program do send the velocity to the topic, so if i but the axe just to the left side just the left motor will get velocity and so on.
Is there package with can do this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245025/package-to-drive-a-robot/) by [Milliau](https://answers.ros.org/users/27715/milliau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-10-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous26353](https://answers.ros.org/users/26353/anonymous26353/) on 2016-10-05**:
I don't know which hardware u have, but there a few packages for differential drive: http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller

And for Arduino boards you can use this one : http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might try the [differential_drive](http://wiki.ros.org/differential_drive) package. The `twist_to_motors` node might be what you are looking for. It takes an input `Twist` message (by default on the `twist` topic, which you will probably want to remap to `cmd_vel`) and computes and publishes motor speeds on two outgoing topics.

If you want to try that package, get it from [the author's GitHub repository](https://github.com/jfstepha/differential-drive) rather than the `code.google.com` location from the ROS. The GitHub location includes changes I submitted to the author to update the package for indigo and later.

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2016-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2